# How to get a percent portion of a balance?

Tags: balances, percent, floating-point-math, safe-math, float

I would like to divide a `Balance` into two parts. One is 10% of `value` and another part is 90% of the `value`. `BalanceOf<T>` is the `Balance` of a pallet.

```rust
    type Balance: AtLeast32BitUnsigned
        + FullCodec
        + Copy
        + MaybeSerializeDeserialize
        + Debug
        + Default
        + scale_info::TypeInfo
        + MaxEncodedLen;
```

```rust
let value: BalanceOf<T> = some_balance;
let deposit: BalanceOf<T> = 0.1 * value;
let actual: BalanceOf<T> = value - deposit;
```

The error message is the following.

```
cannot multiply `{float}` by `<<T as pallet::Config>::Currencies as orml_traits::MultiCurrency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance`
the trait `Mul<<<T as pallet::Config>::Currencies as orml_traits::MultiCurrency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>` is not implemented for `{float}`
```

Another approach is to use sp_runtime::traits::CheckedDiv

```rust
let value: BalanceOf<T> = some_balance;
let deposit = value
    .checked_div(&10u128.into())
    .ok_or(DispatchError::Other("Arithmetic error"))?;
let actual = value - deposit;
```

There I get this error.

```
the trait `From<u128>` is not implemented for `<<T as pallet::Config>::Currencies as orml_traits::MultiCurrency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance`
```

What is the best possible way to approach this safely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually a function as part of the `Imbalance` trait to handle exactly this: [ration](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0f6b5734e8ff52199987b496b2ef7bfd51655198/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/imbalance.rs#L80).

You can see an example of its use to [split transaction fees](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/88d66ac/runtime/common/src/impls.rs#L49L57) between the Treasury and block author in Polkadot.

---

EDIT: Update to do without an `Imbalance`.

There is a better pattern to use if you're not dealing with an imbalance (e.g. a transaction fee that's already been deducted from an account). It is [`from_percent`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8bc45ed/primitives/arithmetic/src/per_things.rs#L94).

This should work (including the option to make it configurable):

```rust
use sp_runtime::Percent;

pub type BalanceOf<T> = 
  <<T as Config<I>>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {

    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {

        // Only needed if you want it configurable:
        #[pallet::constant]
        type DepositFee: Get<Percent>;
    }
}

impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
  fn my_function(value: BalanceOf<T>) {
    // To hard code in a value, you can just use `Percent` directly:
    let deposit = Percent::from_percent(10) * value;

    // If you want it configurable, you can just `Get` the percentage from the config:
    let deposit = T::DepositFee::get() * value;

    let actual = value - deposit;

    /* do your thing... */
  }
}
```

Then, if configurable, you would configure your runtime like:

```rust
parameter_types! {
    pub const DepositFee: Percent = Percent::from_percent(10);
}

impl my_pallet::Config for Runtime {
    type DepositFee = DepositFee;
}
```

Comment: That fits my question really well. Thank you for that. How could I create an imbalance out of a balance?

Comment: Doh, read it too fast. Updated for when just dealing with balances.

Comment: Is `Percent::from_percent(10) * value;` safe? I would expect `checked_mul` or `saturating_mul` in a production environment.

Comment: It's safe, because a portion of a value is always a resulting smaller value. So it's either zero or lower than the value after the multiplication. That's why there can't be an overflow with this operation.

Comment: I noticed this only works with the right order. `let deposit = T::DepositFee::get() * value;` works, but `let deposit = value * T::DepositFee::get();` works not. Do you have any reason for that?